# this.setState Calling only First time

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-state, react-native-video

i have a application in this app i have a video player. when i press "next" button i also pausing video. code is below:

```
onPress={() => 
            {
              this.setState({ isPaused: true }, () => {
              this.props.navigation.navigate('nextScreen')
              });
            }}
```

but when i press next button first time it pauses video and move to nextScreen but if i come back to video player screen and play video again and again press next button nextScreen loads but video is not pausing this time. here is my video player

```
<Video
          onEnd={this.onEnd}
          controls={true}
          onLoad={this.onLoad}
          onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
          onProgress={this.onProgress}
          ref={videoPlayer => (this.videoPlayer = videoPlayer)}
          resizeMode={this.screenType}
          onFullScreen={this.isFullScreen}
          source={require('../Images/Video.mp4')}
          style={{height:'56%', width:'100%', marginTop: 50 }}
          volume={10}
          paused={this.state.isPaused}
          />
```

Comment: when you come back to video screen after clicking back button, react will initialise state with initial state value which you might have set to false. Have you set isPaused  default value to false?

Comment: yes constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {   
    isPaused : false
    }
  }

Comment: have you used this state.isPaused anywhere to pause/play video?

Comment: wait let me most my player code.

Comment: When you come back to your video player screen is the video paused or playing?  I think that probably, When you navigate, your video player screen is not unmounted. It maintain the last "isPaused" state, that is "true". So you have to put your state to "false" to be able to put it to "true" again.

Comment: so please suggest how can i unmount video player?